# Ruby search path different on two boxes with same build of ruby?

Tags: ruby, redhat

We have two servers with the same home-brewed RPM of ruby installed.
One one server, the search path is different, and it fails the following snippet.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'openssl'
require 'digest/md5'
puts OpenSSL::Digest::MD5.new
```

Broken server output:

```
/tmp/test.rb 
/tmp/test.rb:6: uninitialized constant OpenSSL::Digest::MD5 (NameError)
```

Good server output:

```
/tmp/test.rb
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

Broken server with command line flags can be made to work:

```
ruby -I /usr/lib/ruby/1.8 /tmp/test.rb 
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

Both are CentOS 4.4 x86_64, ruby 1.8.6 p369.  We built our own RPM based on Fedora 11 RPM spec file.  It works find on 913 other boxes.
Help?

Answer (score 0):

There's really not much we can do if you don't tell us more about your installation.  You apparently have a broken library search path, but you already knew that.  What is the value of the $: variable on each of the machines?

Edit: Oh, a wild guess: since you're using env, the ruby executable invoked is the first one in your PATH. Are you *sure* there isn't some other ruby installed in /usr/local, for instance, on this particular machine?